# Generate random numbers from a power-law/exponential distribution

Tags: random-generation, exponential-distribution, power-law, quantiles

I'm working through the paper [Power-law distributions in empirical data](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0706.1062.pdf) by Clauset, Newman and Shalizi. On page 12, they generate random numbers from the following distribution: 
\begin{equation*}
 p(x) =
 \begin{cases}
   C(x/x_{\min})^{-\alpha}& x \geq x_{\min} \\[0.5em]
   C \exp(-\alpha(x/x_{\min}-1))& x < x_{\min}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Has someone an idea what would be the best way to generate random numbers from that?

I tried the inverse CDF method that the authors use to generate random numbers from several other distributions they work with (pareto, exponential). However, I could find no inverse (complementary) CDF for the second expression.

I'd be glad if someone could give me a hint on how to tackle this. I could post how I calculated $P(x)$ and tried to find $P^{-1}(x)$, but I don't know if that approach does even work here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: (1) Taking $x_{\min}=1$ (without any loss of generality: this acts like a scale factor), the domain of the density $p$ is $[0,\infty)$, with $\alpha\gt 1$. (2) The distribution is exponential on $[0,1]$ and power on $[1,\infty)$.  (3) Integration shows the relative proportions of the two distributions are $(e^{\alpha}-1)/\alpha$ and $1/(\alpha-1)$, respectively. (4) Thus, you have full information to express $P$ as a *mixture* of a truncated exponential and truncated power distribution.  Since the CDFs of both are easily inverted, your approach will work and produce a simple formula.